# Why am i getting weird character in socket inputstream

Tags: java, sockets, stream

```
//  Portion of code copied from the senders side
clientSocket = new Socket(successor.IP, successor.PORT);
toServer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream()));
String message = "deleteme\n"+predecessor.IP+","+predecessor.PORT;
toServer.write(message);
toServer.newLine();
toServer.flush();


//  Portion of code copied from the receivers side
fromClient = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
toClient = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream()));
input = fromClient.readLine();
```

On the receivers side there are weird characters before the `deleteme`. Like the clubs `♣`.

I want to know from where do these characters come and how to fix the problem? The temporary fix that I am doing is that before I send the `deleteme` message I send some garbage data like `abcd`. Then the deleteme get there as it is.

Comment: @ADi Base64 has nothing to do with anything here. I suggest you delete your comment as it's misleading.

Comment: convert the data to bytes array, send and receive on stream, convert back to string. Close all the streams after you are done with sending and receiving

Comment: @user3001439 There's nothing inherently wrong with the code you're showing (except you should always specify the encoding when using `InputStreamReader` or `OutputStreamWriter`). Is this the actual code you're running? Show a bit more of it.

Comment: @Kayaman: sorry about that.. I thought this might be the issue. I faced the same issues while encryption so I presumed.

Comment: Well, the '\n' is in a strange place in the message. When I use a line-based protocol, I usually put the newline at the end, else 'predecessor.IP+","+predecessor.PORT' get stuffed on at the start of the next message..

Comment: Specifying the charset when using InputStreamReader and OutputStreamWriter is important, because the client and the server may use a different default encoding. Did you try setting it?